# remove all paths with white fill

Tags: batch-file, inkscape

I'd like to remove all white paths in inkscape with the command line. As an example file, take http://paste.xinu.at/ZlfPz/, the two white paths that produce a 3d effect should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No regex, but libxml2.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d "//svg:path[contains(@style, 'stroke:#ffffff')]" *.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's%<path\s[^<>]*\bstroke:\s*rgb\(\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*\)[^<>]*/>%%g' <infile.svg >outfile.svg
```

(Someone will tell you to use proper xml-processing and not regexps, and they will be right. Still, this regexp is at least robust against placement of newlines.)